# Unable to read RFID tag number on my serial console

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to interface RFID(radio reader identification) reader to my raspberrypi3.but unable to read RFID Tag number on my serial console.I am always getting the RFID number embedded on the card as a result of my code.

Code in Python Language

```html
import serial                                                 
def read_rfid ():
   ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0")                   
   ser.baudrate = 9600                                   
   data = ser.read(12)
   ser.close ()                                         
   return data                                           

id = read_rfid ()                                       
print("read card{0}",format(id.decode("utf8","replace")))                                                       #Print RFID
```

Result

```html
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 demo.py
read card{0} 0003626678
```

according to my understanding(correct me if I am wrong),RFID tag (passive tag) has two numbers.one number was embedded on the tag and other was the hidden number.I understood how to calculate the hidden number manually .but I want to see my RFID hidden number on my serial console.I am using python code(python3 GUI)and EM-18 RFID Module.can anyone help me with this.I searched a lot in google and unable to find the solution...please help..

Note:- I Enabled UART interface and it is working fine